# Can we say that the following equation has substantially the same physical meaning as the Dirac equation?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation

Dirac's equation is given by
$$\left[\beta mc^2-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+c \sum ^3_{n=1} \alpha_n p_n\right]\psi(\vec{x},t)=0\tag1$$

Here, $\alpha_n$ in Eq. (1) is an operator having a meaning of velocity. This has been explained in YouTube lecture (in Korean language) cited below. Furthermore, if you check the dimension of each quantity, you can find that $\alpha_n$ should have a meaning of velocity in that $p_n$ has a momentum operator.

Now, consider the following differential equation.
$$\left[mc^2-i\hbar\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\nabla}\right)\right]\psi(\vec{x},t)=0 \tag2$$

If an additional constraint is given as follow:
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{v}=0, \tag3$$

**can we say that Eqs. (1) and (2) have substantially the same physical meaning?**

Here, in order to avoid any confusion, I would like to emphasize that I am not saying the sameness of Eqs. (1) and (2). Eq. (2) has a form that is clearly different from that of Eq.(1).
**I am asking whether the constraint (3) can be used as a bridge to connect Eqs. (1) and (2).**

As is well-known, $\alpha_n$, which are given in terms of Pauli matrices, are related to a spin angular momentum, whereas *Eq. (3) says that $\vec{v}$ is solenoidal* (that is, $\vec{v}=\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A}$).
*This is the reason that I guess that Eq. (3) may be such a bridge or a good constraint.*

**If Eq. (3) is not enough, what else is needed?**

Of course, Eq. (3) may be related to a spin, but Eq. (3) itself does not require a half-spin, as in Dirac’s equation. Nevertheless, it seems that such an issue relies on a form of $\vec{v}=\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A}$.

---

Due to my poor English ability, my response may be delayed. I apologize for such a delayed response, in advance.

- (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uez0yNYFlOo&list=PLyKE9Ujr4dw7TSjsauQjEvswIeerN16em&index=48&t=39m10s)

Comment: Other than the symbol you are using, what makes your $v$ different from your $\alpha$? (Or rather your $c\hbar\alpha$). Like, do you want $v$ to be a vector instead of a set of matrices? Or what?

Comment: Anyways, if $\vec v$ is a vector field, then no, the two equations do not have the same meaning. Because what the heck is this strange new universal vector field $\vec v$ you have introduced? It breaks all kind of symmetries that we know to be unbroken. Why don't we see any evidence of this $\vec v$ field permeating all space? (You don't have this same problem with the Dirac matrices.)

Comment: @hft Thank you for your comment. I need some time  to understand the gist of your comment and to say my opinion correctly. Nevertheless, I can say that $\vec{v}$ is introduced to be defined at each point of the entire space. Please explain how the symmetry breaking is made, when the field is introduced.

Comment: The Dirac theory describes electrons in the vacuum of space. The $\vec v$ field picks out a direction as special, but there is no special direction in vacuum. It breaks rotational symmetry.

Comment: @hft In order to say that there is such a $\vec{v}$ field, some evidence therefor must be provided. However, that topic seems to be irrelevant to my question asking how different the two equations are mathematically. Rather, in a sense, my question is to ask whether or not the solenoidal field required by Eq. (3) can be used as the minimum constraint required to maintain the rotational symmetry mentioned by you.

Comment: @hft Meanwhile, since physics is one of experiment-based scientific disciplines, we should check whether a formula is compatible with all experimental evidences. However, if we hide such a $\vec{v}$ field under a rug while saying that it is something that is not describable classically, can we say that such a hiding is essentially different from the Pauli's process of incorporating the concept of spin into physics? For all that, in this post, I'm not saying that such a field exists, and I'm merely interested in what the mathematical result is when such a solenoidal field is assumed.

Comment: You didn't ask "how different the two equations are mathematically." You asked whether they have "substantially the same physical meaning." I am saying that they do not.